# finding a value of gamma function in terms of $\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

The Gamma function is:
$$
\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,dx.
$$
and I have an integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{2} e^{-x^2}\,dx
$$
I figured out that $\alpha=3$

and if $\alpha = 3 \\ \Gamma(3)= 3*2*1$

But how do I express the value of the integral in terms of $\sqrt{\pi}$?
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{2} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac14\sqrt{\pi}\ ?
$$

Comment: In the $\Gamma$ integral, you have $e^{-x}$. In your integral, you have $e^{-x^2}$, so you must make a substitution (e.g. $u = x^2$) to get a (multiple of a) $\Gamma$ integral.

Answer (score 3):

Using the substitution $u = x^2$, we get $$\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx =  \int_0^{\infty} ue^{-u} (\frac{u^{-1/2}}{2}\, du) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty u^{1/2}e^{-u}\, du = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(3/2) = \frac{1}{4}\Gamma(1/2) = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: got it! thank you! @kobe

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =\sqrt{\pi}$$ and by change of variable $x^2\to u$ should do it.